# Django subquery in insert

Tags: django, subquery, django-orm

Is it possible to force django to make a subquery when I try to insert some values?
This produces two separate queries:

```
CommunicationLog.objects.create(
    device='asdfasdf', 
    date_request=CommunicationLog.objects.get(pk=343).date_request, 
    content_obj_id=338, type_request=1, type_change=2
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely cannot do it by using `create`. There's no available API that will let you do it, since this is very unusual use case. You have to fall back to raw sql.

Answer (score 1):

Using Django 3.2 this now seems to be possible.

```py
CommunicationLog.objects.create(
    device='asdfasdf', 
    date_request=CommunicationLog.objects.filter(pk=343).values("date_request"), 
    content_obj_id=338, type_request=1, type_change=2
)
```

This would execute an INSERT query something like

```sql
INSERT INTO "communicationlog" (
  "device",
  "date_request",
  "content_obj_id",
  "type_request",
  "type_change"
) VALUES (
  %s,
  (SELECT U0."date_request" FROM "communicationlog" U0 WHERE U0."id" = %s),
  %s,
  %s,
  %s
) RETURNING "communicationlog"."id"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the API won't let you do what you want, you can still improve the performance a little bit (which I assume is your intention) by using the [.only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) method when querying the date:

```
CommunicationLog.objects.create(
    device='asdfasdf', 
    date_request=CommunicationLog.objects.only('date_request').get(343).date_request, 
    content_obj_id=338, type_request=1, type_change=2
)
```