# Django insert query results into database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a database table, called 'Tags' like this:

```
   ID   | Name   |  Uses 
 ------------------------
   1    | Python |   0
   2    | Java   |   0
   3    | C++    |   0
   4    | Ruby   |   0
```

I have another table, 'TagMap', that is used to map these tags to users, who can each have many tags.

I want to query the TagMap table to find the total number of times each tag has been used, and then save it to the 'Uses' column for that tag. For example, if 5 users have the tag 'Python', then I want the 'Uses' column to read '5' instead of '0'.

I have looked around online for how to do this, but my main problem is that I'm not sure what I should be searching for, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django will let you query your `TagMap` model (I'm assuming you have a Django model here) to fetch the number of corresponding entries for a given tag.

Then, you'll be able to update the counter of uses in a separate call to the ORM.

Using a raw SQL query, you might be able to do both in a single query, but that's not something the Django ORM allows (see also [Django subquery in insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686559/django-subquery-in-insert)).

Depending on your concurrency requirements, using `select_for_update` in the first query might help you achieve isolation if you want to stick to the ORM for that kind of denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
tag = Tags.objects.get(Name='Python')
count = TagMap.objects.filter(tag=tag).count()
tag.Uses = count
tag.save()
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that code without a disclaimer on possible side effects (e.g. concurrency issues).